# Golang - C source files not allowed when not using cgo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, cgo

When trying to run `go build` in my src directory, I get this error:

> imports runtime: C source files not allowed when not using cgo: atomic_amd64x.c defs.c float.c heapdump.c lfstack.c malloc.c mcache.c mcentral.c mem_linux.c mfixalloc.c mgc0.c mheap.c msize.c os_linux.c panic.c parfor.c proc.c runtime.c signal.c signal_amd64x.c signal_unix.c stack.c string.c sys_x86.c vdso_linux_amd64.c

When I first started learning Go I ran `sudo apt-get install golang` on my Ubuntu laptop (14.04 LTS, 64bit) which installed version 1.2. That ran fine and I was able to build, install and run apps. I then ran autoremove to get rid of it, then installed 1,4 from the golang website.

What's going on here, and how can I fix it? Googling the error shows that it has something to do with a previously installed version of go, but I thought autoremove would clean it and any dependencies up (which it seemed to, as I made sure I couldn't find golang anywhere, before installing from source.

Any clues?

Comment: It might be a silly question, but is the C compiler still installed?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge I think you might be on to something here. The 64 bit version was installed, but I may have needed the 32 bit, even though I'm not building 32 bit binaries. Installing the 32 bit C compiler using instructions from https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InstallFromSource#Install_C_tools seems to have fixed it. Will answer after getting a sample app to build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So James was on the right track. I had gcc installed, but not the 32 bit version. Following advice from https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InstallFromSource#Install_C_tools on how to install the 32 bit version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by unsetting `GOROOT` in the environment. It was pointing to another Go installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to go 1.5. Removing the `/usr/local/go` directory and reinstalling from the tarball fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you install Go 1.4 and then install Go 1.5. But don't change GOROOT environment variables.
Change GOROOT point to GO 1.5 path.